# ioS Nested table: shoots out and deaccelerates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nested-table

Anyone knows how to create a nested table view where the nested table "shoots out and deaccelerates" when tapped upon on in iOS?  (objective c)

I am thinking of an animation similar to this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48118200/motion/transition.html
Different from this however is that the note I am expanding from "underneath" has a larger height dimention than the note that I have to cover it. The image below illustrates the concept:

[image: http://imgur.com/YRovn]

I have tried some UITableViews but so far no luck getting the effect I wanted.

Thank you for your help.

Ed

Comment: Your first link is broken, has a ".d" appended to it, couldn't edit it for you as edit was too small :( Anyways, whenever I've seen that it's not been a separate table view... are you envisioning the cells that pop out scroll independently behind the original cells or something? Also what exactly did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want table cells to slide over each other as they expand out as seems to be happening in your first link with the Flash animation (clicking on the top cell), one idea that comes to mind is to have the views underneath that pop out all really live in the same cell, animate the height change for the cell itself and at the same time animate out the under-views into position at different places at different rates.

Also you want to specify an animation style of EaseOut, which will achieve the slowing at the end you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding/Collapsing TableView you may solve your problem. So Refer below link from apple Library

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html